# Returns nil when getting data from the NOSQL using date query

Tags: date, nosql, nsdateformatter

I am getting response from json and after that I directly save json data into NOSQL table.Actually it is as 12/15/2017 in NOSQL table.But sometimes it stores as 12/4/2017.When I want to get the data from the table using date,it returns empty data.Because I use date format like this dd/MM/yyyy.I don't know how to send exact date format into table and get data from the table.If anyone help me to solve this issue,it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same issue before a week.I used to give date format wrongly.First I gave date format as MM/dd/YYYY.Then how I solved the issue is,I tried below date formatter.Once I changed the date formatter to below format,it works fine.

> M/d/yyy

Comment: I got the solution now.Your answer is working well.Thank you bro.